# How do you slice part of an input statement in Python 3?

Tags: python, indexing, slice

I have a question which asks me to get a user's email address and then return the URL it is associated with. So, for example: 'abc123@address.com' --> 'http:://www.address.com'

I did get this:

```
def main():
    email_address = input('Enter your email address (eg. abc123@address.com): ').strip()
    strip_username = email_address.split('@', 1)[-1]
    the_url(strip_username) 

def the_url(url_ending):
    print('Your associated URL is: http://www.' + str(url_ending))

main()
```

which does what I want, but this code: split('@'...) is something I haven't learned yet. I just found it online. I need to use indexing and splicing for this program, but how can I use splicing if I don't know the length of the user's email? I need to get rid of everything before and including the '@' symbol so that it can leave me with just 'address.com' but I don't know what address it will be. It could be hotmail, gmail, etc. Thanks, and I'm really new to Python so I'm trying to only use what I've learned in class so far.

Comment: @Jamine K, why don't you use `str.index`. you will get the index of `@` and by that you can use slicing like `[str.index('@')+1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

The split method just splits up the string based on the character to you give it, so:

```
"Hello@cat".split("@")
```

Will give you

```
["Hello", "cat"]
```

Then you can just take the 1st index of that array to give you whatever's after the first `@` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `str.split` then by indexing and slicing,
you can do something like this.

```
>>> str = 'abc123@address.com'
>>> 'http://www.' + str[str.index('@')+1:]
'http://www.address.com'
```